# Remove comma and or period except if certain condition holds for last occurrence in R

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to remove all commas and periods from string, except in the case that a string ends in a comma (or period) followed by one or two numbers.

Some examples would be:

```
12.345.67 #would become 12345.67
12.345,67 #would become 12345,67
12.345,6  #would become 12345,6
12.345.6  #would become 12345.6
12.345    #would become 12345
1,2.345   #would become 12345
```

and so forth

Comment: Can you check your examples? `12.234    #would become 12345` or `12.234,34 #would become 12345,67`. Is this really what you mean?

Comment: Thnx corrected them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use negative look ahead syntax `?!` with the `perl compatible` regex:

```
df
#          V1
# 1 12.345.67
# 2 12.345,67
# 3  12.345,6
# 4  12.345.6
# 5    12.345
# 6   1,2.345

df$V1 = gsub("[,.](?!\\d{1,2}$)", "", df$V1, perl = T)
df          # remove , or . except they are followed by 1 or 2 digits at the end of string
#         V1
# 1 12345.67
# 2 12345,67
# 3  12345,6
# 4  12345.6
# 5    12345
# 6    12345
```

Answer (score 2):

a `stringi` solution using same data as @Sotos would be:

```
library(stringi)
```

- line 1 removes the last `,` or `.` character if more than 2 characters follow
- line 2 removes the first `,` or `.` characters if there is more than 1 `,` or `.` left

`x<-ifelse(stri_locate_last_regex(x,"([,.])")[,2]<(stri_length(x)-2),
           stri_replace_last_regex(x,"([,.])",""),x)`

```
x <- if(stri_count_regex(x,"([,.])") > 1){stri_replace_first_regex(x,"([,.])","")}
> x
[1] "12345.67" "12345,67" "12345,6"  "12234"    "1234"     "12.45"
```

Comment: @Sotos, you are right, thanks. Please see updated solution which hopefully works.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to count the characters after the last comma/period (`nchar(word(x, -1, sep = ',|\\.'))`), and if the length is greater than 2, remove all delimiters (`gsub(',|\\.', '', x)`), otherwise just the first one (`sub(',|\\.', '', x`).

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(nchar(word(x, -1, sep = ',|\\.')) > 2, gsub(',|\\.', '', x), sub(',|\\.', '', x))

#[1] "12345.67" "12345,67" "12345,6"  "12234"    "1234"     "12.45"
```

**DATA**

```
x <- c("12.345.67", "12.345,67", "12.345,6", "1,2.234", "1.234", "1,2.45")
```